# How to disable / remove download button on quicklook preview video in Elfinder?

Tags: elfinder

[donwload button on preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHYK4.jpg)

I need to prevent user to download a video from elfinder, I can remove download button in context menu but when preview video there is download button. How to disable / remove download button on quicklook preview video in Elfinder? Is there any configuration on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution, edit configuration client like this

```json
commandsOptions: {
            quicklook: {
                mediaControlsList: 'nodownload',
            },
```